# linking markers together using a line: google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps, markers

I am looking to code a feature that when a user clicks a marker appears then when the user clicks for the next marker it will connect it to the previous marker using a line. I have tried using the google api documentation for this but cannot seem to get the feature to work. can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });

    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
    poly.setMap(map);

    map.addListener('click', addLatLng);
  }

  function addLatLng(event) {
  var path = poly.getPath();

  path.push(event.latLng);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: event.latLng,
  title: '#' + path.getLength(),
  );
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt in your code to add a [google.maps.Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines), what did you try that you thought should work?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates that attempt.

Comment: i edited the question to show the code that i used, it doesn load the map as the error console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" adn also "Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined" but i am not sure on how to fix this

Comment: Add the missing ")".  The code you posted is far from "complete".  You aren't ever setting the path property of the polyline.

Comment: You aren't adding the "map" click listener that calls `addLatLng` until after the first click on the map (it is added inside the first `map` click listener), so the first point doesn't get added to the polyline.

Comment: So where would i position the code. I have the polyline working on a seperate example, but when i place the code in it simply does not work

Comment: What does "simply does not work" mean?  If there are javascript errors, you need to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing is to make the polyline global, then do everything inside the `addLatLng` event handler function:

```
// global polyline
var map;
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
  strokeColor: '#000000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 3
});

// add marker and point to polyline path
function addLatLng(event) {
  var path = poly.getPath();
  path.push(event.latLng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });
};
```

**code snippet:**

```js
// global variables
var map;
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
  strokeColor: '#000000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 3
});

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  map.addListener('click', addLatLng);
  // add the polyline to the map
  poly.setMap(map);
}

function addLatLng(event) {
  var path = poly.getPath();
  path.push(event.latLng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: that is the code i used in the example i said i got working, however when i place that code into the code im using to illustrate infowindows, the code does not work at all

Comment: The code in my answer is different from that in your question.  If you can't add it to your code please,as I requested in my first comment, provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.